# Shutting down X via terminal

Tags: terminal, xorg

I found that the whole X won't react to anything but I was able to log to terminal by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Can I reboot X from the command line without rebooting the whole computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using GDM

To stop/kill X

```
killall gdm
```

To start X

```
startx
```

X should be started at the tty7 `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F7`

Comment: Gdm: No process found

Comment: What are you using, Ubuntu? Gnome? Xfce?

Comment: Ubuntu+lxde. Now ctrl+alt+f8 works but how to kill ctrl+alt+f7?

Comment: Never mind. It was just too big plugin container by Firefox and I managed to kill it by xkill.